# How To Use The Variable Outside The IF

Tags: php, variables, loops

Can you please tell me about how should I use the variable outside the loop that is defined inside the loop. For example:-

```
<?php 
  if($x = 1){
    $abc = 'hello';
  }elseif($x = 2){
    $abc = 'Hey';
  }elseif($x = 3){
    $abc = 'GoodBye';
  }

/* Now below I want to ECHO out $abc but it is not working */
echo '<h3>'.$abc.'</h3>';

?>
```

So what should I do to make $abc work outside the loop?

**edit**

Rollback because the corrections have made the question obsolete.

Comment: There is no loop. Is some code missing?

Comment: Declare the variable outside to the loop.

Comment: oh sorry about saying loop but outside the if statement

Comment: Its not loop its conditional statements, you must first meet them to get variable printed.

Comment: -1 for posting not a real question, the problem description consists of only notorious "not working".

Answer (score 2):

I have improve your code pls check it

```
if($x ==1){

$abc = 'hello';

}elseif($x == 2){

    $abc = 'Hey';

}elseif($x ==3){

    $abc = 'GoodBye';

}

/* Now below i want to ECHO out $abc but it is not working */
echo '<h3>'.$abc.'</h3>';
```

Comment: +1 you are the first to spot his use of `=` instead of `==` in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignemnt `=` operator instead of comparision one `==`

```
$abc = 'Default'; 
if($x == 1){    
    $abc = 'hello';    
}elseif($x == 2){    
    $abc = 'Hey';    
}elseif($x == 3){    
    $abc = 'GoodBye';    
}
```

Comment: ok but now if i echo out $abc outside the IF statement then it does not display anything!

Comment: @JohnPreston: that it is because `X` is not the 1,2 or 3. I updated answer try now

Answer (score 0):

You need proper conditional operator, sensible indentation and else statement

```
<?php 
if($x == 1){
  $abc = 'hello';
}elseif($x == 2){
  $abc = 'Hey';
}elseif($x == 3){
  $abc = 'GoodBye';
} else {
  $abc = 'Default';
}
```